# How to remove unused part of string using another column

Tags: python, pandas

How to remove unused part of string used value in another Pandas column?

I have:

```
Col1         Col2
bbbb2         Hello I want to removebbbb2

Output:
Hello I want to bbbb2
```

I want to use str.extract or any other pandas solution?

EDIT:
@erocoar
But i want to remove in all rows, For example

```
Col1        Col2                                           output
bbbb2     Hello I want to removebbbb2        Hello I want to bbbb2
aaaa1     Hello I want to remaaaa1           Hello I want to aaaa1
```

Your solution is only for one example

Comment: How do you describe "unused part of string "?

Comment: @Rakesh check my edit post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example sub out all the characters other than `bbbb2`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Col1": ["bbbb2"], "Col2": ["Hello I want to removebbbb2"]})

df["Col2"].str.replace("(?:\S*)?(bbbb2)(?:\S*)?", "\\1")

Out[29]: 
0    Hello I want to bbbb2
Name: Col2, dtype: object
```

Edit: For multiple rows, e.g.

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Col1": ["bbbb2", "aaaa1"], "Col2": ["Hello I want to removebbbb2", "Hello I want to remaaaa1"]})
df["out"] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub("(?:\S*)?(" + x[0] + ")(?:\S*)?", "\\1", x[1]), axis=1)

df
Out[127]: 
    Col1                         Col2                    out
0  bbbb2  Hello I want to removebbbb2  Hello I want to bbbb2
1  aaaa1     Hello I want to remaaaa1  Hello I want to aaaa1
```

Comment: Thanks +1, but know how to write regex to remove any char? Your soulution remove only letters, I want to remove also (/, -, . , \...) and others

Comment: Thanks!!!! Do you know how to save "New_sentence in normal case letter not lower? I want to re.IGNORECASE in 33 line, because my col1 is lowercase, col2 Is normal case. https://pastebin.com/84ZPsCib

Comment: Could you give an example? I am not sure right now how the output should be different from what you get using `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: My ['New_sentence'] is normal sentence such as Hello my darling AAA1, but 'Gene_symbol] is written as lowercase 'aaa1' and for compare New_sentence with Gene_symbol i must make New_sentence as lowercase. But on output i want to write to dataframe sentence in Normal case.

Comment: So the output should be `Hello my darling AAA1`? In that case, setting `flags=re.IGNORECASE` will automatically return that, right?

Comment: Yes, the output should be as above, but where i must write flags=re.IGNORECASE?

Comment: Just where you put it in your code already! So e.g. in the given example, it'd become `df.apply(lambda x: re.sub("(?:\S*)?(" + x[0] + ")(?:\S*)?","\\1", x[1], flags=re.IGNORECASE), axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, but in data['New_sentence'] = data.apply(lambda x: cutOff(x['New_sentence'], x['Gene_symbol']), axis=1) 'Gene_symbol' is also lowercase and i cant write here flag = re.IGNORECASE

Comment: I see. A workaround could be to replace the line assigning `n` with `n = [word.lower() for word in words].index(root.lower())` for case-insensitive search

Comment: @Orocoar Thanks! +1

Comment: you know how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067780/how-to-use-lambda-in-pos-tag-with-python-and-pandas

Answer (score 0):

Using `.apply` with `lambda`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":["bbbb2", "aaaa1"], "Col2":["Hello I want to removebbbb2", "Hello I want to remaaaa1"]})
def rep(row):
    s = row["Col2"].split()
    s[-1] = row["Col1"]
    return " ".join(s)

print(df.apply(lambda row: rep(row), axis=1))
```

**Output:**

```
0    Hello I want to bbbb2
1    Hello I want to aaaa1
dtype: object
```