# How to use lambda in pos_tag with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to use lambda x in pos_tag with Python and Pandas?

For example I have:

```
col1    Col2
Aaa1    Hello Aaa1 how are you?
aaa2    Hello my brother aaa2
```

I want use pos_tag for only word from col1.

Output:

```
Hello NNP how are you?
Hello my brother NN
```

I use `data.apply(lambda x: pos_tag(x['col2'], x['col1']))`

but it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import pos_tag
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["Aaa1", "aaa2"], "col2" :["Hello Aaa1 how are you?", "Hello my brother aaa2"]})
df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["col2"].replace(x["col1"], pos_tag([x["col2"], x["col1"]])[1][1]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1                    col2
0  Aaa1  Hello NNP how are you?
1  aaa2     Hello my brother NN
```

Comment: Thanks, but you know how to ignorecase?

Comment: And how to use it in each row in csv file?

Comment: It gives output :         col1                     col2
0  (Aaa1, NN)  Hello Aaa1 how are you?

Comment: @erocoar You know how to do it?

Comment: @jurek. Updated snippet